# Simple MPI_Scatter try

Tags: c++, mpi

I am just learning OpenMPI. Tried a simple `MPI_Scatter` example:

```
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numProcs, rank;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int* data;
    int num;

    data = new int[5];
    data[0] = 0;
    data[1] = 1;
    data[2] = 2;
    data[3] = 3;
    data[4] = 4;
    MPI_Scatter(data, 5, MPI_INT, &num, 5, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    cout << rank << " recieved " << num << endl; 

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

But it didn't work as expected ...

I was expecting something like

```
0 received 0
1 received 1 
2 received 2 ...
```

But what I got was

```
32609 received 
1761637486 received 
1 received 
33 received 
1601007716 received
```

Whats with the weird ranks? Seems to be something to do with my scatter? Also, why is the `sendcount` and `recvcount` the same? At first I thought since I'm scattering 5 elements to 5 processors, each will get 1? So I should be using:

```cpp
MPI_Scatter(data, 5, MPI_INT, &num, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

But this gives an error:

```
[JM:2861] *** An error occurred in MPI_Scatter
[JM:2861] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[JM:2861] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
[JM:2861] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
```

I am wondering though, why doing I need to differentiate between root and child processes? Seems like in this case, the source/root will also get a copy? Another thing is will other processes run scatter too? Probably not, but why? I thought all processes will run this code since its not in the typical if I see in MPI programs?

```
if (rank == xxx) {
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed to run, send and receive buffer must be of same length ... and the data should be declared like:

```
int data[5][5] = { {0}, {5}, {10}, {3}, {4} };
```

Notice the columns is declared as length 5 but I only initialized 1 value? What is actually happening here? Is this code correct? Suppose I only want each process to receive 1 value only.

Comment: Try `MPI_Scatter(data, 1, MPI_INT, &num, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`, since the sendcount is the number of elements you want to send to EACH process, not the count of elements in send buffer.

Comment: @nhahtdh 's comment is the correct answer; it's a common confusion with the scatter/gather operations for people using them for the first time.

Comment: @nhahtdh, maybe u can add an answer then I can mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sendcount` is the number of elements you want to send to **each** process, not the count of elements in the send buffer. `MPI_Scatter` will just take `sendcount` * [number of processes in the communicator] elements from the send buffer from the root process and scatter it to all processes in the communicator.

So to send 1 element to each of the processes in the communicator (assume there are 5 processes), set `sendcount` and `recvcount` to be 1.

```
MPI_Scatter(data, 1, MPI_INT, &num, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

There are restrictions on the possible datatype pairs and they are the same as for point-to-point operations. The type map of `recvtype` should be compatible with the type map of `sendtype`, i.e. they should have the same list of underlying basic datatypes. Also the receive buffer should be large enough to hold the received message (it might be larger, but not smaller). In most simple cases, the data type on both send and receive sides are the same. So `sendcount` - `recvcount` pair and `sendtype` - `recvtype` pair usually end up the same. An example where they can differ is when one uses user-defined datatype(s) on either side:

```
MPI_Datatype vec5int;

MPI_Type_contiguous(5, MPI_INT, &vec5int);
MPI_Type_commit(&vec5int);

MPI_Scatter(data, 5, MPI_INT, local_data, 1, vec5int, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

This works since the sender constructs messages of 5 elements of type `MPI_INT` while each receiver interprets the message as a single instance of a 5-element integer vector.

(Note that you specify the maximum number of elements to be received in `MPI_Recv` and the actual amount received might be less, which can be obtained by `MPI_Get_count`. In contrast, you supply the expected number of elements to be received in `recvcount` of `MPI_Scatter` so error will be thrown if the message length received is not *exactly* the same as promised.)

Probably you know by now that the weird rank printed out is caused by stack corruption, since `num` can only contains 1 `int` but 5 `int` are received in `MPI_Scatter`.

> I am wondering though, why doing I need to differentiate between root and child processes? Seems like in this case, the source/root will also get a copy? Another thing is will other processes run scatter too? Probably not, but why? I thought all processes will run this code since its not in the typical if I see in MPI programs?

It is necessary to differentiate between root and other processes in the communicator (they are not child process of the root since they can be in a separate computer) in some operations such as Scatter and Gather, since these are collective communication (group communication) but with a single source/destination. The single source/destination (the odd one out) is therefore called root. It is necessary for all the processes to know the source/destination (root process) to set up send and receive correctly.

The root process, in case of Scatter, will also receive a piece of data (from itself), and in case of Gather, will also include its data in the final result. There is no exception for the root process, unless "in place" operations are used. This also applies to all collective communication functions.

There are also root-less global communication operations like `MPI_Allgather`, where one does not provide a root rank. Rather all ranks receive the data being gathered.

All processes in the communicator will run the function (try to exclude one process in the communicator and you will get a deadlock). You can imagine processes on different computer running the same code blindly. However, since each of them may belong to different communicator group and has different rank, the function will run differently. Each process knows whether it is member of the communicator, and each knows the rank of itself and can compare to the rank of the root process (if any), so they can set up the communication or do extra actions accordingly.

Comment: "I am not sure if there are any case that sendcount, sendtype are different from recvcount, recvtype." Yes, there are pretty many cases. The receive buffer might be bigger than the message and the `recvtype` might be different (e.g. a user defined datatype) as long as its type map is compatible to the type map of `sendtype`.

Comment: @HristoIliev: I did read about that from the manual. I never tried it myself since I didn't write MPI program apart from school assignment. Feel free to edit if you want to elaborate more on it.

Comment: @HristoIliev: The receive buffer should be larger, but I believe the size of data sent/received by each process must be the same for MPI_Scatter (probably something like sendcount * sendtype = recvcount * recvtype?). I think you removed my point about that.

Comment: No, this is a very common misunderstanding about the receive parameters in MPI. `recvcount` specifies the _size_ of the receive buffer, not the amount of elements that are to be received. `MPI_Scatter(data, 1, MPI_INT, buf, 10, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` is a perfectly valid usage of scatter. That's why there is the `MPI_Get_count` call which provides the actual amount of data received, although it only works with p2p receive operations (since they provide the status).

Comment: @HristoIliev: I don't have a mean to try that out to check for error message. However, according to [this](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cluster.pe.v1r2.pe500.doc%2Fam107_iscat.htm) Unequal message length will cause an error. While in MPI_Recv it does specifies the maximum size of buffer (the message can produce less element than the max size). You can check the revision for the edit about the difference in the count parameter between MPI_Recv (which specifies the buffer size) and MPI_Scatter (which specifies expected number of elements).

Comment: The MPI standard is written ambiguously and obviously different MPI implementors read it differently. Neither Open MPI nor Intel MPI throw such error if one scatters 1 element per rank with a receive size of 2 elements. I would have to test the IBM implementation.

Comment: @HristoIliev: From my understanding of type signature, your example is invalid (10 MPI_INT as opposed to 1 MPI_INT), according to MPI 2.2 standard: http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/docs.html . Whether the implementation throws error or not doesn't matter, but the contract is broken.